# Drop table with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying this code

```
Drop Table Inventory
```

I get error:

> Could not drop object 'Inventory' because it is referenced by a
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to `Drop` the table's constraints and then table

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Inventory')
Drop Table Inventory
```

Comment: I get error: Could not drop object 'Inventory' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
DROP TABLE Inventory CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Comment: `drop table [ur table here] cascade constraints;`

it should work

Comment: @NizarHawawreh:the syntax you gave is  for Oracle and question was tagged for SQLserver

Comment: @theGameiswar , sorry , first hour in stackoverflow ever :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to Drop the Constraint first..

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t2] DROP CONSTRAINT [foreign key constraint]
```

then You can Drop the table

```
Drop table t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all
DROP TABLE Inventory
```

Comment: I get error: Could not drop object 'Inventory' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: That is referenced with which tables??

Answer (score 0):

drop the foreign key constraint from subtable and then drop the main table