# Does order matter in mysql `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <some table>`

Tags: mysql, sql

Does the order matter, when calling `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <some table>` at the top of a SQL script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you call `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS....` after script it will delete already created new table, what most probably you don't want to.

If you call `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS....` before, you make sure that your script won't fail, if the table already exists

Comment: But as long as you call them at the top of the script, the order in which you call the statements will not matter?

for example DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDER
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER.

will not have an influence in regards to foreign keys ?

Comment: It will have influence. Here are some infos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824702/drop-table-with-foreign-key

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerning about foreign keys, then you should first drop child tables. You can not drop a table if it is referenced in another table. But it's easier to temporarily disable key checks.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE ...;
...
DROP TABLE ...;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Then you won't need to care about the order of table drops.

Note that when you enable the key checks, the schema should be "clean" - There should not be any foreign key reference to a not existing table. Otherwise `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` will fail.